# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel cells remain null after setting them

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an application in which I'm trying to write to an Excel file. It doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Image2Excel {
class Engine {
    public static void go(string imageFilename, string excelFilename = null) {
        //Image img = Image.FromFile(imageFilename);
        Bitmap btm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageFilename, false);
        Image img = Image.FromFile(imageFilename, false);

        if (btm != null) {
            Color[][] colorArray = new Color[btm.Width][];
            for (int x = 0; x < btm.Width; x++) {
                colorArray[x] = new Color[btm.Height];
                for (int y = 0; y < btm.Height; y++) {
                    colorArray[x][y] = btm.GetPixel(x, y);
                }
            }

            var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            var worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "sheet1";

            worksheet.Cells[1,1] = "top left";
            worksheet.Cells[1,2] = "top right";
            worksheet.Cells[2,1] = "bottom left";
            worksheet.Cells[2,2] = "bottom right";

            workbook.SaveAs("temp.xlsx");
            workbook.Close();
            excel.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    } 
}
}
```

I'm trying to write some text to the first 4 cells in the spreadsheet. It's not working. When I open the file, I see nothing in the cells.

I do see that the sheet name is set to what I set it to so I know it's writing to the files.

One thing I noticed when I debug is that worksheet.Cells[1,1] is null after I set it. I'm wondering if I need to set the cell to an object before writing to it. But I'm not sure how. I don't seem to be able to do this:

```
worksheet.Cells[1,1] = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Cell();
```

Hovering over Cells tells me it's a Range object, but I'm not sure how to set it to a range either. I tried this:

```
worksheet.Range["A1"].Value = "hello";
worksheet.Range["A1"].Value2 = "hello";
```

...but those don't work either. worksheet.Range remains null just like worksheet.Cells.

How can I make sure worksheet.Cells[1,1] or worksheet.Range["A1"] is set to an object that will take a string value? Thanks.

You can find my application on github: https://github.com/gibran-shah/Image2Excel

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15.0.4795.1000.

I have Excel 2010 installed on my computer.

Comment: Try worksheet.Cells[1,1].Value = "top left";  OR 
excel.Cells[1,1].Value = "top left";

Comment: There must be something else going on. I copy/paste the code you have and it appears to work as expected. The text was saved successfully in the Excel file. Are you sure your looking at the right Excel file? With no path, the file will get saved into the bin folder of the project. Possibly set the Excel app visible with `excel.Visible = true;` and put a break point before you save and close.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using the correct interop version? I am guessing Excel 2010 uses version 14. How did you install the interop? I recommend you drop the current interop version and simply reference the interop version on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yours but could you try these methods? it worked for me.

## 1st method with `Worksheets.Cells`

```
// CREATE EXCEL OBJECTS.
Excel.Application xlApp;

Excel.Workbook xlWB;
Excel.Worksheet xlWS;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();

// Specify the path to the excel file
xlWB= xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path/to/xlFile.xls");

// Choose the sheet you want to open
xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

// Write on the single cell 
xlWS.Cells["1", "D"] = "Example";

// Save the change and quit
xlWB.Close(true);
xlApp.Quit();
```

## 2nd method with `Worksheets.get_Range()`

```
// CREATE EXCEL OBJECTS.
Excel.Application xlApp;

Excel.Workbook xlWB;
Excel.Worksheet xlWS;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();

// Specify the path to the excel file
xlWB= xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path/to/xlFile.xls");

// Choose the sheet you want to open
xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

// Write on the range of cells 
xlWS.get_Range["A3", "D5"] = "Example";

// Save the change and quit
xlWB.Close(true);
xlApp.Quit();
```